# Flexbox: text item `font-size: 0' and taking up space

Tags: html, css, font-size, flexbox

```
div { display: flex
    ; font-size: 0
    ; justify-content: space-between
    }

div > a { font-size: 10pt }
```

­

```
<div>
  Banana
  <a>Meat grinder</a>
  <a>Phone</a>
</div>
```

[Live](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNNaJb)

Why does the Flexbox text item take up space when its `font-size` is set to `0`? Is there a way around it, e.g. selector for the text items? Assume I can't access the HTML.

Comment: It doesn't take space as long as I can tell ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec says:

> [**4. Flex Items**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-items)
>
> Loosely speaking, the [flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-item) of a [flex container](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-container) are
>   boxes representing its in-flow contents.
>
> Each in-flow child of a [flex container](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-container) becomes a [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-item),
>   and each contiguous run of text that is directly contained inside a
>   [flex container](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-container) is wrapped in an anonymous [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-item).
>   However, an anonymous flex item that contains only [white space](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop)
>   (i.e. characters that can be affected by the [`white-space`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-3/#propdef-white-space)
>   property) is not rendered, as if it were `display:none`.

Therefore, this behavior you observe is caused because your text is wrapped in an anonymous flex item, even if your text is not displayed because of `font-size: 0`.